# How to create a loop to pick up data from a list and copy it into the appropriate worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a code which copy a new entry into the appropriate worksheet based on its ItemType value. I'm sorted out about a new entry, thanks to guys from this website.

```
Sub Data_Entry()
    Dim wsDict As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim NoRow As Long, NextRow As Long
    Dim ItemNumber As String, ItemType As String, Issues As String, InventoryValue As String

    Set wsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With wsDict
        .Add Key:="Mfg FG", Item:="ABCX Mfg FG"
        .Add Key:="Mfg Raw", Item:="ABCX Mfg RAW"
        .Add Key:="Mfg Sub-Assy", Item:="ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy"
        .Add Key:="Resale", Item:="ABCX Resale"
        .Add Key:="Conv Resale", Item:="ABCX Conv Resale"
        .Add Key:="Mfg FG PE", Item:="ABCX Mfg FG PE"
        .Add Key:="Mfg Sub-Assy PE", Item:="ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy PE"
        .Add Key:="Acrylics", Item:="ABCX Acrylics"
        .Add Key:="Mfg Raw PE", Item:="ABCX Mfg Raw PE"
        .Add Key:="Mfg FG PVC", Item:="ABCX Mfg FG PVC"
        .Add Key:="Mfg Raw PVC", Item:="ABCX Mfg Raw PVC"
        .Add Key:="Mfg Sub-Assy PVC", Item:="ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy PVC"
    End With

    ItemNumber = InputBox("Please enter Item Number", "Item Number", "Type here")
    ItemType = InputBox("Please enter Item Type", "Item Type", "Type here")
    Issues = InputBox("Please enter Number of Issues", "Issues", "Type here")
    InventoryValue = InputBox("Please enter Inventory Value", "Inventory Value", "Type here")

        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
            NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
             .Range("A" & NextRow).Value2 = ItemNumber
             .Range("F" & NextRow).Value2 = ItemType
             .Range("H" & NextRow).Value2 = Issues
             .Range("I" & NextRow).Value2 = InventoryValue

             .Range("A" & NextRow - 1 & ":I" & NextRow - 1).Copy
             .Range("A" & NextRow & ":I" & NextRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
             Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

        If wsDict.exists(ItemType) Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsDict(ItemType))
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not ws Is Nothing Then
                With ws
                    NoRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                    If NoRow < 13 Then NoRow = 13
                    With .Cells(NoRow, "A")
                        .Value2 = ItemNumber
                        .Offset(0, 1).Value2 = Issues
                        .Offset(0, 2).Value2 = InventoryValue
                    End With
                End With
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Item Not Found"
        End If
    End Sub
```

However, I need some code with the same destination rules to apply on data already in the list. I don't know whether it is possible to assing variables within `Do Until IsEmpty` loop. It pops up an error Invalid Qualifier. What does it mean?

```
Option Explicit
Sub auto_populate()

Dim wsDict As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim NoRow As Long, NextRow As Long
Dim i As Range
Dim ItemNumber As String, ItemType As String, Issues As String, InventoryValue As String
i = 2

Set wsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With wsDict
    .Add Key:="Mfg FG", Item:="ABCX Mfg FG"
    .Add Key:="Mfg Raw", Item:="ABCX Mfg RAW"
    .Add Key:="Mfg Sub-Assy", Item:="ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy"
    .Add Key:="Resale", Item:="ABCX Resale"
    .Add Key:="Conv Resale", Item:="ABCX Conv Resale"
    .Add Key:="Mfg FG PE", Item:="ABCX Mfg FG PE"
    .Add Key:="Mfg Sub-Assy PE", Item:="ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy PE"
    .Add Key:="Acrylics", Item:="ABCX Acrylics"
    .Add Key:="Mfg Raw PE", Item:="ABCX Mfg Raw PE"
    .Add Key:="Mfg FG PVC", Item:="ABCX Mfg FG PVC"
    .Add Key:="Mfg Raw PVC", Item:="ABCX Mfg Raw PVC"
    .Add Key:="Mfg Sub-Assy PVC", Item:="ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy PVC"
End With

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))
   ItemNumber.Value = Cells(i, 1)
   ItemType.Value = Cells(i, 6)
   Issues.Value = Cells(i, 8)
   InventoryValue.Value = Cells(i, 9)

       If wsDict.exists(ItemType) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsDict(ItemType))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            With ws
                NoRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                If NoRow < 13 Then NoRow = 13
                With .Cells(NoRow, "A")
                    .Value2 = ItemNumber
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value2 = Issues
                    .Offset(0, 2).Value2 = InventoryValue
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Item Not Found"
    End If
   i = i + 1
Loop
```

Here is the idea, I need to pick up data in the row 2 from the cells: A,F,H and I; assing them variables at this order: "A" = ItemNumber, "F" = ItemType, "H" = Issues
and "I" = InventoryValue. Then I need to copy ItemNumber,Issues and InventoryValue based on ItemType into the appropriate worksheet. Lastly, It should do the same process all the way down until it encounters an empty row.
I would like to make it reusable so that some code to remove duplicates or filter out data already in those sheets is desirable. 
I found this code to remove duplicates. I don't know how to put it all together.

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange(*).RemoveDuplicates
```

Comment: Are you familiar with Excel Power Query? It makes getting data from various types of sources and combining into a refreshable data source very easy.   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-microsoft-power-query-for-excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll definitely take a look at Excel Power Query.